# Integral inequality for $C^1$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $f\in C^1[0,1]$ be a function such that $f(0)=0$ and $0\leq f'(x)\leq 1$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$. I want to prove that
$$
\int_0^1 [f(x)]^3 \; dx \leq \left( \int_0^1 f(x)\; dx \right)^2.
$$
I tried by defining
$$
g(x) = \int_0^x [f(t)]^3\; dt \quad\text{and}\quad h(x)=\left( \int_0^x f(t)\; dt \right)^2,
$$
then the desired inequality becomes $g(1)\leq h(1)$. Computing the first and second derivatives of $g$ and $h$ we obtain
$$
g'(x) = [f(x)]^3, \quad h'(x) = 2 f(x) \int_0^x f(t) \; dt 
$$
and
$$
g''(x) = 3[f(x)]^2 f'(x), \quad h''(x) = 2[f(x)]^2 + 2f'(x)\int_0^x f(t)\; dt.
$$
As $f(0)=0$, we obtain that $g'(0)=0$, $h'(0)=0$, $g(0)=0$ and $h(0)=0$, and as $0\leq f'(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$, we conclude that $0\leq f(x)\leq x$.

From this it follows that
$$
g''(x)/3\leq [f(x)]^2, \quad h''(x)/2\geq [f(x)]^2
$$
and all I was able to conclude from the above (integrating twice) is that $g(x)\leq 3h(x)/2$ for all $x$, but this is far from the goal, so this is not a good approach. Is there any way to prove that $g(1)\leq h(1)$?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279054/42969 – found with Approach0: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%20%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Bf(x)%5D%5E3%20%5C%3B%20dx%20%5Cleq%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cint_0%5E1%20f(x)%5C%3B%20dx%20%5Cright)%5E2.%20%24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}\left(\int_{0}^{1} f(x) d x\right)^{2}-\int_{0}^{1} f^{3}(x)\, d x&=
2\int_0^1 f(u)\left(\int_0^u f(v)\,dv\right) du\\
&\qquad\qquad- \int_{0}^{1}f(u)\left(\int_0^u D(f^2(v))\,dv\right)du
\\
&=2 \int_{0}^{1}f(u)\left(\int_{0}^{u}  f(v)\left(1-f'(v)\right) d v\right)d u 
\end{align}
and the RHS is $\geq 0$ by the given assumptions.

Comment: Cool$\phantom{filler}$

Comment: It’s a duplicate (easy to find with Approach0)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SbMH.png)

This is the problem-solving method I typed with the mathtype ， I hope you can adopt it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.