# Prove $\int_{0}^{1} f^{3} (x) dx \leq \left(\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx\right)^2$

Tags: calculus

If f(x) is differentiable on [0,1] and $0 \leq f'(x) \leq 1$ and f(0) = 0

Prove $\int_{0}^{1} f^{3} (x) dx \leq \left(\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx\right)^2$

Well I know f(x) is increasing function but that's it, I don't have idea to do the question. Is this related to Riemann Sum?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87305/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20f%5E%7B3%7D%20(x)%20dx%20%5Cleq%20%5Cleft(%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20f(x)%20dx%5Cright)%5E2%24)

Comment: I am studying the link given by both of you

So instead of using integral from 0 to 1, I need to use a more general integration from 0 to x?

I also found this link:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281166/help-with-an-inequality-with-integrals?noredirect=1

In that link, the working started from f'(x) ≤ 1 and integrate both sides with respect to x to get f(x) ≤ x. Then how to obtain f(x) ≤ x?